# How to import a single variable from a scss file angular?

Tags: css, angular, variables, sass

I have a global styles.scss file where I have declared some variables. I need to use this variable in a component's scss file. I know I can declare a class in styles.scss using this variable and then use this class in my components template file, but the elements on which I want to use these variables are generated later, so I am using ng-deep in my components scss file and applying css rules in this ng-deep. I don't want to import the entire styles.scss file as it is very large. Is there a way in which I can import only a single or a list of variables from styles.scss into my components scss file?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible that ways. If you do not want to import complete `styles.scss`, maybe you can put the variables in another `scss file`, let's say `variables.scss` and import `variables.scss` in both `styles.scss` as well as your `component's scss`.